# Where is http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name defined?

Tags: security, identity, claims-based-identity, claims

OASIS owns the http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity namespace, but I can't find anywhere that defines the "name" claim type. There are other claims like First Name, Last Name, Email Address, etc. but no claim that just refers to Name.

Is there an authoritative location where this claim type is defined? I'm interested in understanding the correct usage of this claim.

Answer (score 9):

The only source I could find right now that mentions the namespace, is the Windows Identity Foundation documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes_members.aspx

Though I cannot find it at the moment, it seems to me that Microsoft used an official source. I don't think it would otherwise have been implemented.

Just found an interesting thread: [Correct usage of the Name Claim (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1d36671f-fcb7-48b5-b590-82c6e125af66/correct-usage-of-the-name-claim-httpschemasxmlsoaporgws200505identityclaimsname?forum=Geneva)